# ML.NET in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compatibility, ml.net

I  cannot figure out how to use ML.NET in Unity.

What I did:
Converted my project to be compatible with framework 4.x.
Converted api compatibility level to framework 4.x.
Made assets/plugins/ml folder and droped in Microsoft.ML apis with corresponding xmls.
Marked all ml.dlls platform settings to be only 86_64 compatible (this was redundant).

I can now:
Call ML apis and create MlContext, TextLoader, and do the training of a model. When a model is trained I can also evaluate the trained model, but...

I cannot:
When trying to get a prediction out of the model I get an error:
[github comment on issue from 28.12.18](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/1886) (there is also a whole project attached there, you can see the code  there)
The same code works in visual studio solution.

```
 public float TestSinglePrediction(List<double> signal, MLContext mlContext, string modelPath)
{
    ITransformer loadedModel;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(modelPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        loadedModel = mlContext.Model.Load(stream);
    }
    var predictionFunction = loadedModel.MakePredictionFunction<AbstractSignal, PredictedRfd>(mlContext);
    var abstractSignal = new AbstractSignal()
    {
        Sig1 = (float)signal[0],
        Sig2 = (float)signal[1],
        Sig3 = (float)signal[2],
        Sig4 = (float)signal[3],
        Sig5 = (float)signal[4],
        Sig6 = (float)signal[5],
        Sig7 = (float)signal[6],
        Sig8 = (float)signal[7],
        Sig9 = (float)signal[8],
        Sig10 = (float)signal[9],
        Sig11 = (float)signal[10],
        Sig12 = (float)signal[11],
        Sig13 = (float)signal[12],
        Sig14 = (float)signal[13],
        Sig15 = (float)signal[14],
        Sig16 = (float)signal[15],
        Sig17 = (float)signal[16],
        Sig18 = (float)signal[17],
        Sig19 = (float)signal[18],
        Sig20 = (float)signal[19],
        RfdX = 0

    };
    var prediction = predictionFunction.Predict(abstractSignal);
    return prediction.RfdX;
}
```

This is the method that returns an error line:
`var predictionFunction = loadedModel.MakePredictionFunction<AbstractSignal, PredictedRfd>(mlContext);`

Comment: I have submited an isue on a github where anyone can download unity example project and VS api project.  [link](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/1886) . Just unzip and start unity project, the error is shown as soon as the Unity editor starts, no need to press play.

Comment: update:I have managet to setup unity in a way I can now import ML dlls and train models, but when trying to make a prediction I came across this error: (similar code works in .net framework 4.7.2 solution)
ArgumentException: method arguments are incompatible
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure, ... FULL DESCRIPTION ON : https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/1886

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follows is a bit modyfied **Iris Example** from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/iris-clustering (that one does not work anymore due to some ML API changes)

1. First make sure that you have the latest .net version installed and that your Unity version is at least 2019.2.0f1 (this was a preview version) or higher.
2. Creste a new unity project. Create a Plugins folder inside your Assets folder. Import all ML .Net APIs into that folder (Might be a foolish thing to do, but I have forehand created a visual studio soution and added all those APIs to that solution via nuget, and than just copied those dll files to Assets/Plugins folder in my unity project).
3. In Assets folder create an Data folder and paste iris.data file from https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/test/data/iris.data into it.
4. Create a script named MLuTest and paste into it the following code:

   public class MLuTest : MonoBehaviour{

   ```
       static readonly string _dataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Assets", "Data", "iris.data");
       static readonly string _modelPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Assets", "Data", "IrisClusteringModel.zip");
       MLContext mlContext;
       void Start()
       {
           Debug.Log("starting...");
           mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
           IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.ReadFromTextFile<IrisData>(_dataPath, hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ',');
           string featuresColumnName = "Features";
           var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms
               .Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth")
               .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName, clustersCount: 3));//read and format flowery data
           var model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);//train
           using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_modelPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))//save trained model
           {
               mlContext.Model.Save(model, fileStream);
           }
           var predictor = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<IrisData, ClusterPrediction>(model);//predict
           IrisData Setosa = new IrisData
           {
               SepalLength = 5.1f,
               SepalWidth = 3.5f,
               PetalLength = 1.4f,
               PetalWidth = 0.2f
           };
           Debug.Log(predictor.Predict(Setosa).PredictedClusterId);
           Debug.Log("...done predicting, now do what u like with it");
       }
   }

   public class IrisData
   {
       [LoadColumn(0)]
       public float SepalLength;

       [LoadColumn(1)]
       public float SepalWidth;

       [LoadColumn(2)]
       public float PetalLength;

       [LoadColumn(3)]
       public float PetalWidth;
   }
   public class ClusterPrediction
   {
       [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
       public uint PredictedClusterId;

       [ColumnName("Score")]
       public float[] Distances;
   }
   ```

This should work right out of the box ... well it did for me. Where you could mess up is when getting api files, they could be different version from mine or just some .net framework compatible. So get the content of my Plugins folder (mind you all those apis may not be necesery, do the cherrypicking yourselve):https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/1886
It used to be (in previous unity versions) that some player settings had to be changed but i did not have to do it. But anhoo here are mine:
[image: slika]

I hope this helps, since Unity update 19.2 I have not had any problems mentioned in previous posts in this thread.

Comment: I am sorry for the code formating but this tool... a lot of really bad words

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Unity 2018.1, unity can target .net 4.x. So you would need to set the .net version to .NET 4.x Equivalent, or .net standard 2.0 (https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/28/updated-scripting-runtime-in-unity-2018-1-what-does-the-future-hold/) and make sure you add your dll to the project as a reference in visual studio. If you don't add it as a reference, then visual sudio doesn't know about it.

Comment: Ok, that solved the problem of api not beeing detected, but now I get three errors as soon as I add an api which uses Microsoft.ML;  : "Assembly 'Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Reference has errors 'MLAIFramework'." Here MLAIFramework' is my api. The second error says: "Assembly 'Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Reference has errors 'Assembly-CSharp'."

Comment: But there are no errors visible in my api before build in VisualStudio.

Comment: As soon as I ad a Microsoft.ML.'someClass'  call to my API methods or into fields I get the above mentioned errors and an app will not run.

Comment: Try changing the scripting backend to IL2CPP.

Comment: Did that too but got no beter result.

Comment: That commonly occurs (an "Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:" message) when a DLL/plugin is added that targets the wrong framework or has MSIL code/features in it Unity's compiler/build tools doesn't support ... for example, trying to use .NET 7 or 8 DLL with new language/framework features not present in Unity ...

Answer (score 1):

As Nick said in his post**, it should work with Unity if you follow those steps.

However, at the time I am writing this post, the ML.NET team has not yet done comprehensive testing with Unity, so it's not completely surprising that it's not working out of the box. [This issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/1886) has been opened on the [ML.NET Github repository](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/). I suggest keeping an eye on that issue for the status of Unity support.

** Nick:
`Starting with Unity 2018.1, unity can target .net 4.x. So you would need to set the .net version to .NET 4.x Equivalent, or .net standard 2.0 (https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/28/updated-scripting-runtime-in-unity-2018-1-what-does-the-future-hold/) and make sure you add your dll to the project as a reference in visual studio. If you don't add it as a reference, then visual sudio doesn't know about it.`

Comment: Hi Roman, if Mich would deleted His answer and the links would expire there mit much bei legt to see your Post aus an answer, could you try to make it ne able to stay Aline?

Comment: Yes, I have opened that issue on athe github repository and have also contacted Unity's cheefe framevork 4.x developer about that, and a guy on Github promised to test this til the end of jan '19... Aldo I am not shure the error is not on my side. I am now trying to build an ML.NET api that wuld run in any kind of(c#)environment, but cannot get it to work. It is as though ML libs are not added to the build. Will be posting my findings here...